# Can't Invade or Summon

Tags: dark-souls-2

I see bloodstains and illusions, but I can't see summon signs or invade. I have undone all ports for Dark souls 2, and I'm not in champions covenant.   I've use the bone of order it said "can't use at this time".

I don't know what to do?

Comment: What platform are you on? PC? Console?